# Odd Umbraco backend behavior after deployment

Tags: configuration, umbraco

I've had this before, but can't seem to replicate the steps I did back then.
I've got an Umbraco 4.5.2. site which is running on port 8084 in a development-environment. All works well.

When I want to publish the website to the production server, the umbraco-backend seems to want to keep using the port 8084 and therefor my backend (starting at login) is really strange. Can't seem to update any content (or anything else for that matter).

Now, I assume, it has something to do with caching of sorts, but what setting to change (or what to delete)?

This is my login-screen (no red border on erronous login)
[image: login on production]

And this is my back-end (there is content - i can see content in the front-end - just not visible in the content-tree);

[image: backend on production]

This is my back-end on the development machine (did nothing but crude copy and edited the database connectionstring to match my production database).

[image: backend on development]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you change the port number? I am assuming you're putting it into the hostname on the root item in umbraco content tree.

Have you tried republishing the entire site to make sure the published links do not contain the port number?

Comment: The portnumber is the IIS binding. I never hardcode any urls inside Umbraco (not needed)

Comment: BTW I can not republish entire site since I don't have any context-menus. I've added two images to clarify my problem.

Comment: Are you sure it is looking for the port number? This looks like either a permissions problem or umbraco is looking for files in the wrong location. Have a look with fiddler what is going wrong.

Comment: By the way, if you do set a hostname in the Umbraco backend, you get the benifit of dates and prices (decimals) being in the correct locale for your site.

Comment: Seems security was the issue. The AppPool user had no access to the App_Data folder so.. the cache was never updated. Thanks!